# Java RSA-OAEP generate key pair

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am trying to interface with external system which requires to send an RSA-OAEP SHA-256 public key with key size of 2048.
I am getting an error that the key has wrong bit length: '2350' .
I tried online encryption/decryption services using the generated KP and they seems to accept the key. What I am doing wrong?

```
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

    generator.initialize(2048, random);

    KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
    Key pubKey = pair.getPublic();
    Key privKey = pair.getPrivate();

    // I am sending pubKey.getEncoded()
```

Example result of the public key:

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuUKRnE07rwQ8Juegbhabv1kaHOrfou8+FNHYyhjn8jUPgwumALonsvztt4goivc1Bwm6sFwCIGnxf+2y1BI1saG3w5S1R24EUAN7efi7CS4LMEhtgJtavtWYEkEZj7OaU/BLnkB1rFAmBDU3vudSd3Gupgnbqtw7VjOH6Qrfnsh3phVr6DdHruq7SftOvCyhBucOax0hwt6enRs5UjBfbgDbbSMFaFdF4jZpE4Jnfl9gwRF51QP934Il1djPT6cezuEYlD8VAklLFPR+rOL73nvBCxLdZwdBlQHO8J8XGjWaNmAMHvyisFxkD8Ud9nC7m9MPb9J6+n3cWG7OL+C97QIDAQAB
```

Thank you

Comment: You code shows you generating a key and encrypting data but doesn't show you sending anything.

Comment: Yes, it is part of the code handling decryption down the line as well. Last line has comment what I am sending -> pubKey.getEncoded() .

Comment: We'd need to see how the api is defined. Your public key is a valid base64 formatted SPKI, which is a very commonly accepted format, but other formats are also possible. Perhaps they only want the modulus and are assuming the public exponent is 65537. It's impossible to know without more information.

Comment: When decoding the public key data it is showing these details: Type: RSA, Size (bits): 2048, Public Exponent (e): 65537 (0x010001), so your sample key has the correct size/length of 2048 bits.Maybe the 3rd party needs a PEM-format or or or??

Comment: The problem is I was not given more information. They say it should be base64 binary with bit length of 2048. The algorithm to do encryption/decryption should be RSA-OAEP SHA-256

Comment: @MichaelFehr I know, I posted the question because I am starting to think I overlooked something.
I was thinking the same of sending the modulus but the say it should be base64 binary which would be weird.

Comment: So what is the 3rd party API you are working with? Is there any further description of the API available?

Comment: It is internal API delivered by 3rd party. They wrote only:
It is using algorithm RSA-OAEP with key of size 2048 bits encoded with SHA256. And that the service accepts binary base64 public key.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are only supposed to send your base64-encoded modulus, not your entire public key. Trying doing that by base64 encoding the output of `((RSAKey) pubKey).getModulus().toByteArray()` and see if that works.

Comment: The same thing crossed my mind and right now I am testing it. But it is totally weird. They say public key not modulus from the public key.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: if they want exactly 2048 bits in base64, drop the first (sign) byte from `BigInteger.toByteArray()` (RSA moduli are chosen to have exact-multiple-of-8 bitsizes so they always have an extra sign byte in the signed representation output by `BigInteger`).